# Check against an Entire list to validate user information

Tags: c#, xamarin, foreach, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm just not getting this.

So I have a list from my API

Of Customers called a

I need to validate weather the fields correlate to any of the 100+ Logins that I'm suppose to receive from the Resposne

How I'm Going about it At the moment

```
foreach (var c in Users.a)
{
    if (Email == c.email && Password == c.password)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Success", "", "Ok");

        Application.Current.Properties["Email"] = c.email;
        Application.Current.Properties["Userid"] = c.id;

        Users.Loggedin = true;

        await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Home(c.email));
    }
    else
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Fail", "Please enter correct Email and Password", "OK");
    }
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way of doing this.

The Call

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://Site/wp-json/wc/v3/", 
                            "ck_a25f******************dcd0",
                            "cs_8f247c22************05c");

WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
var x = await wc.Customer.GetAll();
Users.a = x;
```

Comment: At first, requesting a list of credentials doesn't look like a good ideal to me, let's hope it will be at least via https. If you are in control of the API do the check there and only return if login was successful. 
If you have to do it the way you do right now you might use LINQ to find the corresponding user `a.Where(c => c.email == Email && ...)`

Comment: I 100% agree this is a terrible idea but its my requirement, I'm not its the Woo commerce *https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-customers API *  Ill have a look at Linq forgot about it, The issue is Theres a return of 148 Objects Then I have to query every single one to check if the login info matches so I can save the Users Email and ID to the localstorage and then use that as a constant so they can place orders and such

Comment: Mind Writing me a Example LINQ query to have a look at.

          x.Where(c => c.username == email && c.password == Password);

Then where is the if true do this part come

Comment: The result of the where is the matching results, in your case you expect there to be no match (in case of failed login) or one match (in case of success). Of course you also could in the first step use the where only, to get the entry for the user you need and afterwards you can continue using this for an if statement to check the password. This way you can distinguish between user doesn't exist and password incorrect. BTW: You should not have different messages for these cases because you would enable attackers to find out the usernames.

Comment: Do you have performance issues with this right now? Iterating over 148  objects should not be a big problem. Do you expect that number to rise in the future? I agree that you should use the Linq way described above.

Comment: I'll mess around with this Thanks a mil, I surprisingly don't , No I wont every store has there own login and that's it. Ima have to use linq because I can only pull a 100 then I have to index "Page" for the other 48 Which is a tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Came to the Conclusion that my best way forward with this was to Fetch => Add => Combine Until My list was empty.

```
 RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://Yoursite/wp-json/wc/v3/", "Customer Key", "Customer Secret");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);


            int pageNum = 1;
            var isNull = false;
            List<Customer> oldlist;

            while (!isNull)
            {

                var page = pageNum.ToString();
                x = await wc.Customer.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {
                    "page", page
                }, {
                    "per_page", "100"
                }
            });
                oldlist = FetchCustomers.customers ?? new List<Customer>();
                if (x.Count == 0) {


                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    pageNum++;

                    FetchCustomers.customers = oldlist.Union(x).ToList();


                }

            }
```

How i'm Validating

```
 var list = FetchCustomers.customers.ToList();

            foreach (var user in list)
            {

                if (user.username == Usernamelabel.Text)
                {
                    Application.Current.Properties["CId"] = user.id;
                    Application.Current.Properties["CEmail"] = user.email;
                    Application.Current.Properties["CUsername"] = user.username;
                    Users.Loggedin = true;
                    Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Phase 2 Done your logged in ", "OK");


                }
            }
```

User is Validated From username I'm busy with another Process to Validate the user by The Wordpress API and getting a JWT token then Sending it to this Method to validate and Fetch the Customer and then Persisting the User.

**Here's that Extra Method I mentioned**

```
 var client = new WordPressClient("http://Youtsite/wp-json/");
            client.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;
            await client.RequestJWToken(USername, Password);

            var x = client;
            var isValidToken = await client.IsValidJWToken();

            WpApiCredentials.token = client.GetToken();

            if (isValidToken)
            {

                Login_Phase2();
            }
            else
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Token not Found", "OK");
            }
            #endregion
```